# NotNull JSR 303 Validation on cascaded validation

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, spring-mvc, bean-validation

Using Hibernate validator, I have an object graph with

```
Class ObjectA {

    @Valid
    ObjectB objectB;
}

Class ObjectB {

    @NotNull(groups = {OnSubmission.class})
    @Past(groups = {OnSubmission.class})
    public Date getDateOfThing() {
        return dateOfThing;
    }
```

Object A is validated by a controller mapped method

```
private String validate(@Validated({ OnSubmission.class }  @ModelAttribute("objectA") ObjectA objectA, BindingResult bindingResult)
```

Dates in the future are validated fine. Null dates are not being validated.

On  the hibernate validator doc pages http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.1/reference/en-US/html_single/
it says

"Note that null values are getting ignored during cascaded validation"

Is this a statement of fact or a bug or a limitation of JSR 303?

What is the solution other than custom validation?

Thanks

Comment: You are requestiong to validate goup `OnSubmission.class` but the `@Valid  `annotation on `Object object b;` does not belong to this group. Try using `@Valid(groups={Onsubmission.class})`.

Comment: I'm not sure @Valid supports groups. I don't think this is the problem either. I can see validation talking place for the date field. It validates if the date is in the future. It doesn't validate a null date......